# Paper of Paul Erdös

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to understand *[On Arithmetical Properties of Lambert Series](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1948-04.pdf)* by Erdös, but am stuck on the first page.

He states:

> Put $k=\left[(\log n)^{1/10}\right]$ and let $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ be the sequence of consecutive primes greater than $(\log n)^2$. (...) From elementary results about the distribution of primes, it follows that $p_i < 2(\log n)^2$ for $i \leq \frac{k(k+1}{2}$.

I think the "elementary results" refers to Bertrand's Postulate.  But, from that, I can only say $(\log n)^2 < p_1 < 2((\log n)^2)$ -- not the statement about all $p_i$ for the given $i$.  How is this result obtained?

He further states:

> Put $$A = \left\{\prod_{1\leq i \leq \frac{k(k+1)}{2}} p_i\right\}^t$$
>   (...) by a simple computation, we obtain $$A < \left\{2(\log n)\right\}^{tk^2} < e^{(\log n)^{1/4}}$$

How does this follow?

Finally, the page ends with a listing of congruences.  Let's say the first congruence is true. Is there a guarantee that all other congruences will be true as well?

Comment: How are related $k$ and $n$?

Comment: $k=(logn)^{1/10}$

Comment: I've attempted to make your question self contained by including quotes from relevant portions of Erdös' paper, as well as including the title of the paper.  (This staves off link rot.)  Might I suggest turning the congruence part of the post into a separate question, given that it's somewhat different than the components related to bounds on prime numbers?

Comment: The first result comes from Bertrand's Postulate indeed, which implies that $p_i<2p_{i-1}$